# How to fill top and bottom space using android:drawableLeft inside Button

Tags: android, button, android-widget, android-xml

I am using `android:drawableLeft` to put drawable on button, but getting like this:

[image]

How to `match height of drawable` with Button's height ?

As you can see i am getting `space on top and bottom`, but i `want to fill this space` by my facebook icon.

see what i am using:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/fb_bg"
            android:text="Login with Facebook"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/fb_icon"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:drawablePadding="0dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

`fb_icon` and `fb_bg` (**size** of both the `drawables` are same - `40 x 40`)

Comment: either use images of same size, remove `android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"` also padding of linear layout

Answer (score 0):

Remove padding of parent and margin of `Button`

Use this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/fb_bg"
        android:text="Login with Facebook"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/fb_icon"
        android:drawablePadding="0dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```